# Can namedtuples be used in set()?

Tags: python, set, tuples, namedtuple

I know that `namedtuple` is a factory function to create classes with immutable data fields. I'm assuming they are hashable so that they can be used in sets. My worry is if there are any gotchas associated with using namedtuples in sets. e.g. are there issues if there are nested `namedtuple`s?

Comment: What problem did you have when you tried it?
If they're mutable at any level, you won't be able to use them in a set.  If they're entirely immutable, then you can use them freely in a set.

Comment: my worry is if a field of my `namedtuple` would contain a mutable object during run time, and if that would affect things (which it would). I think I can design things in a way to make sure that does not happen

Comment: Then test your tuple before you add it to the set, or wrap it in a `try-except` block.

Comment: how do you test it before adding it to the set? just run `hash(...)` in a `try-except` before adding?

Comment: search "Python test hashable".

Comment: `isinstance(..., typing.Hashable)` should do it.

Comment: @sabik: [Nope.](https://ideone.com/k71wRW) That gives false positives. Just call `hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are hashable, and can be used in sets, like `tuples`.
The gotcha is that a tuple of mutable objects can change underneath you.

Tuples composed of immutable objects are safe in this regards.

Not sure it is a gotcha, but it is worth noting @user2357112supportsMonica's remark in the comments:

> The other gotcha is that a namedtuple is still a tuple, and its
> `__hash__` and `__eq__` are ordinary tuple hash and equality. A `namedtuple` will compare equal to ordinary `tuples` or instances of unrelated
> `namedtuple` classes if the contents match.

Comment: so as long as a tuple is not comprised of mutable objects it should be ok. e.g. no lists in fields?

Comment: Yes, immutable objects would be safe.

Comment: The other gotcha is that a namedtuple is still a tuple, and its `__hash__` and `__eq__` are ordinary tuple hash and equality. A namedtuple will compare equal to ordinary tuples or instances of unrelated namedtuple classes if the contents match.

Comment: Good point @user2357112supportsMonica , I added your remark to my answer.